# Issue with Yarn Install

Tags: docker, jenkins, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

```
I am installing yarn packages inside a docker container using Jenkins pipeline (yarn install --verbose). It throws an error while fetching packages. I get this error on console "Killed" as it is Jenkins job. Any suggestions or advices most welcome. Thanks in advance
```

- free -m #memory utilized by the container running by Jenkins job
                total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
  Mem:          31456       15849        1496         295       14111       14919
  Swap:             0           0           0
  [Pipeline] sh

  - yarn install
    yarn install v1.10.1
    [1/4] Resolving packages...
    [2/4] Fetching packages...
    java.io.EOFException

  Killed

  ERROR: script returned exit code 137
  Finished: FAILURE

Comment: You're going to have to get more logs for anyone to help you with this. "It throws an error while fetching packages" isn't enough for a diagnosis.

Comment: Usually "Killed" message comes in when your process eats more memory than what the container can give. Try increasing memory - but spender's right, you'll need to give more information for better answers

Comment: I have added the logs